# How to find and access microchip with USB connectivity and python

Tags: python, usb, port

I have this ADS1299EEG PDK board which is used for EEG capturing. It comes with its own software and driver.
I want to access the board with my own python script to get the data for interpretation.
Their software is written in C and it is not accessible.

So far I have tried many things, but have not been successful. I have something with PyVisa, but still stuck at the beginning.

```
import visa
rm = visa.ResourceManager()
rm.list_resources()
itc4 = rm.open_resource("COM4")
itc4.write("V")
print(itc4.read())

2019-07-31 11:57:15,632 - pyvisa - DEBUG - No visa library specified, 
trying to find alternatives.
2019-07-31 11:57:15,634 - pyvisa - DEBUG - Environment variable 
PYVISA_LIBRARY is unset.
2019-07-31 11:57:15,638 - pyvisa - DEBUG - No user defined library files
2019-07-31 11:57:15,647 - pyvisa - DEBUG - Automatically found library 
files: []
2019-07-31 11:57:15,648 - pyvisa - DEBUG - Did not find NI binary
2019-07-31 11:57:15,649 - pyvisa - DEBUG - pyvisa-py is available.
2019-07-31 11:57:15,650 - pyvisa - DEBUG - Reusing ResourceManager with 
session 8301957

WITH ERROR 
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'interface_type'
```

Comment: Are you using Windows?  Do you see a serial port for the board in your Device Manager?

Comment: I recommend ditching the MMB0 motherboard and use your own microcontroller solution.

Comment: David Grayson : Yes. im using windows 10. i cant see a port in the device manager. it get connects only with the MMBO software.

Comment: Turbo J: I m using their evaluation board for experimenting. after experimenting i am going to make my own microcontroller. at the moment i need this board since there evaluation board has many advantages like noise cancelling and high amplification etc...